# EventBus with more fragment

Tags: android

I have 2 fragments A contain by activity A and B contain by activity B. 
The flow off them: from A to B.
I want to use EventBus to communicate with A and B instead of Local Broadcast.
Can I do it? If it can, how?

Comment: Definitely you can. Regarding how - please read EventBus documentation, check the samples, read tutorials, and then come back to SO if you're still not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but EventBus only work on a fragment, not more fragments. So I ask in here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but `EventBus` will only work if your fragment is alive.

Recently i have found [this](http://androidgig.com/eventbus-library-in-android/) nice tutorial about `EventBus`.

according to docs,

> EventBus simplifies the communication between components

So yes you can use it, for more information you can refer official [Github](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) repository

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Otto bus](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-EventBusOtto/article.html) for this.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question the OP asked. Additionally, if you'd like to advocate for Otto, then please explain how to use it to achieve what the OP is asking about.